How do I set up conditional formatting for values that contain text from a cell in another tab?
From similar problems I found online, I've tried a number of regexmatch and combined it with indirect but nothing seems to work.
Here's a sample of my sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GXdnvo7hnzDn94ybl9SCUzLr-vSZtFG1WHolYvhOfic/edit?usp=sharing
In the "Milestones V2" tab, I want to conditionally format columns A and E based on the values from the Instructions tab, A2, A3, A4, etc.
For example:

If Instructions tab A2=EDCI, then Milestones tab A2:A8 and E2:E8 should appear green because they contain EDCI, the same value as Instructions tab A2.
If Instructions tab A3=DSCI, then Milestones tab A9:A15 and E9:E15 should appear blue because they contain DSCI, the same value as Instructions tab A3.

This workbook is intended to be duplicated by multiple teams so each team will use different values in column A of the Instructions tab, which will later be used throughout the workbook.

INDIRECT
To access other sheets, from conditional formatting, you will need to use INDIRECT:
Range: A2:A,E2:E
Rule:  =REGEXMATCH($A2,INDIRECT("INSTRUCTIONS!A2"))
You could alternatively hide a =INSTRUCTIONS!A2 reference somewhere in the same sheet and then point your rule there.
